# Simplest set and forget distributed database for storing simple JSON like structures?

Tags: java, database, json, nosql, distributed

I have a reasonably simple a reasonably system that are conceptually 100,000's of small/simple **JSON** documents. I want to switch from mysql to a distributed system for redundancy and backup purposes.

Its currently written in **java**. What will be the simplest/easiest nosql solution to install and use? i.e. I want something I can just install on a few servers, point to each other, and start using.

I don't want to spend hours learning, tweaking and configuring stuff. (If its going to be too large a project I may as well just write some java code that synchronizes the relevant tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) is easy to install and start to use document database for me.

It is easy to make it work with [java](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial) and it has a nice mapper from java objects to mongo called [morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/).

Answer (score 1):

If you can tolerate hosting your data on Google's AppEngine, Ubud-db can be something for you:
https://bitbucket.org/f94os/ubud-db/wiki

Ubud-db is a document store on AppEngine with a REST-JSON API. Spring/Jackson maps from JSON to a Map, and then Ubud's service maps from the Map to Entity, persisted by the Datastore.

Answer (score 0):

How can I ask this question if you've already asked it!?

I'll add `BaseX` to the list -- it handles `JSON` fine.  Has a nice GUI, or you can just use a console through `bash` et. al.

Geared towards `XML` with `XQuery` and `Xpath`, but has `JSON` modules.

I'm only looking at alternatives because I'm not quite sure how to use some of the features...but that's on me, not the db.

usage example:

```
  let $content := file:read-text('x.json')
  let $json := json:parse($content)
  return admin:write-log($json)
```